# IntelliJ is unable to resolve symbol core from org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am following this [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-oauth2login) to implement authentication on my Spring Boot App with Google. IntelliJ doesn't recognize core from org.springframework.security and reports cannot resolve symbol 'core'.

I have already added the latest version of dependency for oauth2-core:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

The class which I am trying to add is as follows:

```
public class ClientRegistration {

private String registrationId;
private String clientId;
private String clientSecret;
private ClientAuthenticationMethod clientAuthenticationMethod;
private AuthorizationGrantType authorizationGrantType;
private String redirectUriTemplate;
private Set<String> scopes;
private ProviderDetails providerDetails;
private String clientName;
}
```

ClientAuthenticationMethod and AuthorizationGrantType are to be imported from the core library which my project is unable to load so far.

What could be the possible cause?
I am using Spring Boot 2.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error vanished after I invalidated the cache and restarted IntelliJ.